# Two consecutive greater-than signs

Tags: beamer, symbols

How do I produce the output >> in a LaTeX Beamer presentation?

When I write `>>` or `\textgreater\textgreater`, I get this symbol, which I believe to be the guillemet(»):

[image: »]

I do not want this symbol. I want literally two greater-than symbols, in the context of

> Use >> to append to a file, as in `date >> dates`

Comment: In what context do you want this symbol to occur? Is this a prompt?

Comment: Typing `>>` was once a way to obtain `\guillemotright` if `babel` was loaded with the `french(b)` option. But the latter consists in only one symbol (`»`, unicode 00187), and you can have it directly in any  unicode editor with a suitable keyboard driver. You can obtain something similar in maths with the `\gg` command.

Comment: If you don't want the symbols to be considered part of the same ligature, then use `>{}>`.

Comment: @Jubobs I've updated the question. Although it has been closed as a duplicate, I do not understand how it's a duplicate - I do **not** want the guillemet, but an output that is literally >>.

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much, that solves my problem. Do you want to make it as a formal answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Being this a command, I would use (probably embedded somewhere) a `\verb` command. You will need it for other things, like `#` or similar... compare   `>{}> \texttt{>{}>}  \verb|>>|`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to avoid the automatic combining of characters, separate them using an empty group `>{}>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
>> >{}>
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want/need this to work with LuaTeX then something like `>\null>` or `\>\hbox{}>` is needed as LuaTeX doesn't treat `{}` as breaking up the ligature here.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the math mode `\gg` just for that symbol. If you think they are too close together, you could use `>>` (again in math mode) with some negative space `\!` between them to bring them together a bit.

```
\(\gg\)
\(>\!\!>\)
```

[image]

Comment: I would make this a logical markup command, such that the OP does not have to type it all over again (either the one or the other form)

Comment: But don't want that symbol. I do want two greater signs.

Comment: Something like `\texttt{>>}`?

Comment: @erik Yes, but without the code formatting that texttt brings